# PHPExcel. Считывание из файла по ячейкам

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

```js
  echo $uid = (string) $table - > getCellByColumnAndRow('A', $i);
  echo "-".$balance = (string) $table - > getCellByColumnAndRow('B', $i);
  echo "-".$start_bonus_added = (string) $table - > getCellByColumnAndRow('C', $i);
  echo "-".$expires_at = (string) $table - > getCellByColumnAndRow('D', $i);
  echo "-".$fio = (string) $table - > getCellByColumnAndRow('E', $i);
```

считываем из файла,в выводе выводиться подобное

```js
zzzzzzzzzzzzz01-zzzzzzzzzzzzz01-zzzzzzzzzzzzz01-zzzzzzzzzzzzz0
```

хотя в файле
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем прикол? и как его решить?о.о

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю почему такое было,но решилось таким способом считывания

```js
$uid=(string)$table->getCell('A'.$i)->getValue();
```